# Heroku & HHVM deployment problems

Tags: heroku, hhvm

I deployment to heroku after additing HHVM in my composer.json.
HHVM is not installed locally on my computer, so I compilling through

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Heroku return errors:

```
Generating optimized autoload files
    > php artisan clear-compiled
    sh: 1: php: not found
    Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error

      [RuntimeException]                   
      Error Output: sh: 1: php: not found  

    install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...

!     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app
```

Before adding HHVM deploy is normal.
Tell me what is missing

Answer (score 0):

Composer executes the commands in the `scripts` section of `composer.json` exactly as they're written. It's likely that your `composer.json` `scripts` key looks like this:

```
"scripts":{
    "post-install-cmd":[
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd":[
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd":[
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
```

You'll have to change these scripts to point to `hhvm` instead:

```
"scripts":{
    "post-install-cmd":[
        "hhvm artisan clear-compiled",
        "hhvm artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd":[
        "hhvm artisan clear-compiled",
        "hhvm artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd":[
        "hhvm --php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
        "hhvm artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
```

Note that this will break the post-install scripts on your local, development machine unless you install hhvm.